# An easy question about if clauses

Tags: conditional-constructions

I wanted to make a sentence with the words **discipline** and **succeed**.

> While preparing for TOEFL I realized that if I don't have discipline, I won't succeed.

Or

> While preparing for TOEFL I realized that if I hadn't had discipline, I couldn't have succeed

For instance, I took the test 3 years ago and 10 months before the test I realized

> Unless I have discipline I will fail.

In this situation I think the first sentence is correct but I am a little confused because I realized it in the past so that's why I should make this sentence for past so it's like the second one.
Thanks for answers

Comment: Please delete your [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299553/it-is-about-if-clauses) at EL&U as cross-posting the same question is not allowed on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrected sentences would be :

> - While preparing for TOEFL, I realized that if I don't have discipline, I won't succeed.
> - While preparing for TOEFL, I realized that if I don't have discipline, I won't be successful

and

> While preparing for TOEFL, I realized that if I hadn't had discipline, I wouldn't be successful.

and

> - Unless I have discipline, I will fail.
> - Unless I have discipline, I will be a failure.

Comment: Thanks for correction. But which sentence would give the meaning of stuation?

Comment: They all mean the same thing. That is, "unless you are disciplined, you have a chance of being a failure, which in turn means a lack of success.". The first couple of sentences specifies when you realized this statement, where as the last sentence is a meager generalized statement.